# How to use language_in or jscomp_off with Google Closure Compiler Service API

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Is it somehow possible to pass command line flags like `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5` or `--jscomp_off=internetExplorerChecks` to the Google Closure Compiler Service API? I can't find it in the [Service API Reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref).

For reference, `jscomp_off` is documented in [Warnings](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings) and `language_in` is documented in [JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/JavaScript).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Additional-Webservice-Options

You can use "language" as a webservice option.  Through the UI add:

```
// @language ECMASCRIPT5
```

to the compiler configuration comment block.

Comment: Thanks! That gave me what I needed to figure it out for REST (using the POST data tab). The URL parameter is `language=ECMASCRIPT5` (vs. `language_in=ECMASCRIPT5` like the command line).

Comment: note that you can also do:  
`// @language ECMASCRIPT6` `// @language_out ECMASCRIPT5`